How to get data from a dynamic custom table-like element of a legacy desktop application? (table not detected by pywinauto)
I want to get data from the table of a legacy Windows desktop application.
I tried pywinauto - the scroll bar, titles, checkboxes, tabs are detected but the table is not detected.
I found few tab controls called TKalosGrid which I thought could be the table, but it's children and descendants are empty.
Tab control:
<hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper - '', TKalosGrid, 525516>, 
<hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper - '', TKalosGrid, 788142>, 
<hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper - '', TKalosGrid, 591206>, 
<hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper - '', TKalosGrid, 2032892>,

Few Commands I tried:
>>> grid1 = window.child_window(handle=525516)
>>> grid1.exists()
>>> grid1.children()
>>> grid1.descendants()
>>> grid1.print_control_identifiers()
>>> grid1.dump_tree()
>>> grid1.wrapper_object()

The table changes according to the tab selected and the table data keeps updating in real-time.
Please Note that I do not want to use OCR
Any programming language can be used.

